# Why does splice not fill the holes on a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, splice

Suppose that you run this code:

```
var a = [];
a[4] = true;
```

Then your array would look like `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, true]`

But if you run this code:

```
var a = [];
a.splice(4, 0, true);
```

You would get `[true]` instead of, well, `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, true]`

When using splice, if the index exceeds the current length of the array it just stops at the last element.

Why is this the intended behavior for splice?

Comment: What is the javascript engine / browser you are using?

Comment: Maybe you should directly contact someone working at the ECMScript standard? Stack Overflow is not necessarily the best place to get an authoritative answer about particular language design decisions.

Comment: Using Chrome 27, that is not the behavior that I observe. When I assign `a[4] = true`, I receive the following array: `[4: true]`.

Comment: @andre.barata Chrome v27... // Don't know about the JS's but V8 complies with ECMA-262, 3rd edition

Comment: @bfuoco: `[4: true]` doesn't look like an array.

Comment: Assigning to an array in the manner described in the question yields an associative array with one key/value pair where the key is '4' and the value is 'true'. (in my very limited tests, at least).

Comment: @bfuoco Just try `var a = []; a.splice(4, 0, true); console.log(a);`

Comment: @bfuoco: You are right in so far that the array will only have one "real" element with key "4". All arrays are just objects after all. It would still be wrong to say that it generates an "associative array". Arrays simply work this way in JS. The array elements are just properties of the underlying object.

Comment: With the latest version of chrome on OSX i get `[undefined × 4, true]` http://screencast.com/t/pTLjUYc6

Comment: _"Then your array would look like `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, true]`"_ - Not quite. `a[4]=true` adds an element at index `4` and sets the `.length` to `5`, but it doesn't add `undefined` elements at the previous index positions. It may look that way if you do a `console.log(a)`, and `a[0]===undefined` will be `true`, but that's because accessing properties that don't exist returns `undefined`, not because the properties exist and have been set to the value `undefined`. You can see that elements `0` through `3` don't actually exist because (`0 in a`) is `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the ECMA docs, the 'start' argument cannot be greater than the length of the array or it is set to the length of the array.

> 5 - Let relativeStart be ToInteger(start).
>
> 6 - If relativeStart is negative, let actualStart be max((len + relativeStart),0); else let actualStart be min(relativeStart, len).

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12

As for why exactly: I'm not sure, maybe they thought it would be counterintuitive if the method added items to the array.